# Different template variations in magento categories

Tags: magento-1.9, template

I want different versions of my template (different header CSS mainly) for different categories, i am using the "porto" template. how can i do this in CE 1.9?

I have made and copied the default folder out of skin/frontend and renamed it but it doesnt show in the categories custom design dropdown.

Thank you in advance

Comment: To make the new design package and theme appear in the categories custom design dropdown, please create directory under app/design/frontend

Comment: Hi i did that but it doesnt show in categories > custom design dropdown.

Answer (score 3):

You can use design update.

Go to `Category > Custom design` tab and Choose "Your theme" in "Custom Design section" then paste following code in "Custom Layout update" section:

```
<reference name="head">
     <action method="removeItem"><type>css</type><name>css/old-css.css</name></action>
     <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/new-css.css</stylesheet></action>
</reference>
```

This will remove the default css and add new css for you.

**Remember both files need to be in same place - `skin/frontend/theme_pack/theme_name/css` folder**

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi there what happens if its text i need to change or the menu? thank you.

Comment: If you want to change text, then should `replace template- .phtml` file.

Comment: using that design update it says "XML data is invalid."

Comment: Sorry, check updated answer, I had missed `name` in `<reference name="head">`